# Parsing each field and process it using 'awk'/'gawk'

Tags: unix, awk

Here is a query:

```
grep bar 'foo.txt' | awk '{print $3}'
```

The field name emitted by the 'awk' query are mangled C++ symbol names. I want to pass each to [dem](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E22003/dem.1.html) and finally output the output of 'dem'- i.e the demangled symbols.

Assume that the field separator is a ' ' (space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
grep bar 'foo.txt' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs dem | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: The way I read the dem man page, the symbol names should be on the command line rather than stdin

Comment: oops, I misread that. I edited in a call to xargs which should fix it.

Comment: well, the c++ side could have spaces in them :)

Comment: yeah my c++filt stuff won't work with his (apparently) Sun mangling style :/. but you may lucky maybe dem doesn't put spaces into the c++ side? from what the examples show, it omits showing the return type, at least

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is a pattern matching language. The `grep` is totally unnecessary.

```
awk '/bar/{print $3}' foot.txt
```

does what your example does.

**Edit** Fixed up a bit after reading the comments on the precedeing answer (I don't know a thing about `dem`...):

You can make use of the `system` call in awk with something like:

```
awk '/bar/{cline="dem " $3; system(cline)}' foot.txt
```

but this would spawn an instance of `dem` for each symbol processed. Very inefficient.

So lets get more clever:

```
awk '/bar/{list = list " " $3;}END{cline="dem " list; system(cline)}' foot.txt
```

**BTW**-- Untested as I don't have `dem` or your input.

---

Another thought: if you're going to use the `xargs` formulation offered by other posters, `cut` might well be more efficient than `awk`. At that point, however, you would need `grep` again.

Answer (score 1):

This will print the demangled symbols, complete with argument lists in the case of methods:

```
awk '/bar/ { print $3 }' foo.txt | xargs dem | sed -e 's:.* == ::'
```

This will print the demangled symbols, *without* argument lists in the case of methods:

```
awk '/bar/ { print $3 }' foo.txt | xargs dem | sed -e 's:.* == \([^(]*\).*:\1:'
```

Cheers,
V.